# Fedora 27 не работают php вставки в html

Tags: php, html, apache

Есть сто процентно работающая конфигурация сервера apache на centos 7. Потребовался перенос на Fedora 27. Команда

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep php
```

не находит php вообще. В conf.modules.d есть файл 15-php.conf следующего содержания

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule prefork.c>
    LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>


<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !prefork.c>
    # ZTS module is not supported, so FPM is preferred
    # LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7-zts.so
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

test.php c phpinfo выдает нормальную информацию. В какую сторону рыть ума не приложу. Файл .htaccess есть

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
AddHandler php-script .htm .html
```

В Fedora 26 этот конфиг то же работает. Возникает подозрение на переход с php5  на php7

Answer (score 0):

.httpaccess не видел такого файла, может [.htaccess](https://blog.ukrnames.com/hosting/predstavlyaem-vashemu-vnimaniyu-podborku-iz-24-pravil-dlya-htaccess)?

Comment: да, описка была

Answer (score 0):

в общем проблема решилась после чтения документации. Дело в том, что с 27 Fedora пошел переход с mod_php на php-fpm для работы с php. Решилась проблема достаточно просто. В файле /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf нужно закоментировать строку

```
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

и раскоментировать `LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so`